# What is postgres equivalent header for informix sqlhdr.h

Tags: postgresql, ecpg

I am migrating my application from informix to postgres. As my application is cpp based I was using esqlc to compile it. Now I am getting error `sqlhdr.h not found`...

Comment: Please can you review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide?
Your question is not currently in a form that will get much of a response

Comment: Hey, Welcome to stackoverflow see this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you check the [ECPG chapter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg.html) in the manual?  There is even a chapter about [Informix Compatibility Mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg-informix-compat.html). All available header files for Postgres are stored in the `include` subdirectory of your Postgres installation.